# simplemodal contact form does not close after sending mail in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, simplemodal

i am using the simplemodal contact form for my website. it works perfectly on safari, firefox and opera on mac os, and firefox and chrome on windows. the only issue i have is with ie8. when i click the "send" button the mail is actually sent but i get an error message (alert window with "unknown" in it) and then everything seems to be in some infinite loop with the "loading.gif" turning and turning. it never gets to the step where i ahve the message "your mail has been sucessfully sent" although like i said the mail is sent.

any idea where the problem is coming from ?
thanks for your help.
frank

Comment: Have you modified the code at all? Do you have a link I can view?

Comment: sorry, for the late answer. no i haven't modified the code at all. and i forgot to precise few things. i use the version 1.3.4 of simplemodal along with jquery 1.4.2. the problem occurs with ie8 under windows xp.
i actually tried using your code in the 1.3.4 zip file (just changing the $to variable in the php file) and the problem is the same. you can try it in fmphotography.free.fr/stockphotography/contact/